# Failing test cases on Set! on Kattis

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem on Kattis called Set!. It can be viewed [here](https://open.kattis.com/problems/set).

This is my solution:

```
from sys import stdin
ls=[]
ls_output=[]
ls_final=[]
ls_answer=[]
output=''
for i in stdin:
    ls+=i.split()
ls1=dict(list(enumerate(ls,1)))
dc={v:k for k,v in ls1.items()}
ls_values=list(ls1.values())

for i in range(len(ls_values)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(ls_values)):
        for k in range(j+1,len(ls_values)):
               ls_output.append([ls[i],ls[j],ls[k]])

for m in ls_output:
    if all(len(set([m[0][n], m[1][n], m[2][n]])) in [1, 3] for n in range(4))\
    and m[0]!=m[1]!=m[2]!=m[0]:
        ls_final.append(m)

if ls_final:
    for x in ls_final:
        for y in x:
            ls_answer.append(dc[y])
    for z in range(0,len(ls_answer),3):
        output+=f'{ls_answer[z]} {ls_answer[z+1]} {ls_answer[z+2]}\n'
else:
    output+="no sets"
print(output)
```

For some reason, it always fails the 8th test case (passing 7/31 cases). I cannot figure out what's wrong with the code as it looks correct to me, as a beginner. (I'm not asking for anyone to optimize my code. I know that it could be improved and be made more efficient, beautified. But that is not my main point. Also, please do not provide a solution from some GitHub repo. I'm interested in learning only from what I coded here. And yes, I've already tried consulting Chat-you-know-who)

#Updated the code according to a suggestion to do away with dictionaries and prevent the duplicates problem. Still had the same result (8th test case failed).

```
from sys import stdin
ls=[]
ls_output=[]
ls_final=[]
ls_answer=[]
output=''
for i in stdin:
    ls+=i.split()
#enumerated ls1 and then unpacked the tuples to form ls2
ls2=[]
ls1=list(enumerate(ls,1))
list(ls2.extend(item) for item in ls1)
##ls1=dict(list(enumerate(ls,1)))
##ls_keys=list(ls1.keys())
##
####dc={v:k for k,v in ls1.items()}
##ls_values=list(ls1.values())

for i in range(len(ls)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(ls)):
        for k in range(j+1,len(ls)):
               ls_output.append([ls[i],ls[j],ls[k]])

for m in ls_output:
    if all(len(set([m[0][n], m[1][n], m[2][n]])) !=2 for n in range(4)):
        ls_final.append(m)

if ls_final:
    for x in ls_final:
        for y in x:
            ls_answer.append(ls2[ls2.index(y)-1])  ##ls2=[1,3SOP,2,2DOP,3,1STP..]
    for z in range(0,len(ls_answer),3):
        output+=f'{ls_answer[z]} {ls_answer[z+1]} {ls_answer[z+2]}\n'
else:
    output+="no sets"
print(output)
```

Edit:

This is the correct solution (thanks to @ggorlen), keeping parts of my original code (dictionary) while eliminating other data structures/ possibility of duplicates being indexed wrongly. The code is more concise and solves all test cases now.

```
from sys import stdin
stdin=open('std.txt','r')
ls=[]
ls_final=[]
output=''
for i in stdin:
    ls+=i.split()
ls1=dict(list(enumerate(ls,1)))

for i in range(len(ls)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(ls)):
        for k in range(j+1,len(ls)):
               acc=[]
               acc.append(ls1[i+1])
               acc.append(ls1[j+1])
               acc.append(ls1[k+1])
               if all(len(set([acc[0][n], acc[1][n], acc[2][n]])) !=2 for n in range(4)):
                   ls_final.append([i+1,j+1,k+1])
ls_final=[j for i in ls_final for j in i]

if ls_final:   
    for z in range(0,len(ls_final),3):
        output+=f'{ls_final[z]} {ls_final[z+1]} {ls_final[z+2]}\n'
else:
    output+="no sets"
print(output)
```

Comment: Does it tell you what the expected and actual results on the failing test case are?  What about the input?

Comment: No it doesn't. The test cases are hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fundamental logic looks correct. Although you've discounted simplifying and refactoring your code, that's exactly what I did to pass the tests.

Here's my solution, which starts with your solution and strips out unnecessary intermediate steps and data structures:

```py
from sys import stdin


found = False
cards = []

for line in stdin:
    cards.extend(line.split())

for i in range(len(cards)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(cards)):
        for k in range(j + 1, len(cards)):
            x, y, z = cards[i], cards[j], cards[k]

            if all(len(set([x[i], y[i], z[i]])) != 2 for i in range(4)):
                found = True
                print(i + 1, j + 1, k + 1)

if not found:
    print("no sets")
```

My hunch was that using the card's index information directly would handle duplicates. This constraint isn't discussed in the description, leaving open the possibility that it could account for the hidden failures.

Your approach, using a dict to map each card to its index, will fail in the presence of duplicates as two cards will both map to the same index. In my version, duplicate cards still preserve their separate indices.

Morals of the story:

1. Try to solve problems directly, with a minimum of steps. Every step and piece of complexity added introduces a potential failure point.
2. Don't be too hasty to reject refactoring as a tool to fix logical problems. Simplification can reveal hidden characteristics that may not be obvious in a complex design.
3. Revisit the problem constraints to consider edge cases like duplicates. As [Kelly mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76355038/failing-test-cases-on-set-on-kattis/76361767#comment134653553_76361767), coding challenges that are ostensibly modeled after real-life domains often break rules in those domains, as appears to be the case here, since [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)) isn't supposed to have duplicate cards.
4. Format your code with [Black](https://github.com/psf/black) and adhere to [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). Smushed-together style makes the logic less comprehensible.

Comment: 4. Forget your background knowledge. Like that in the *real* game, there are no duplicates.

Comment: Appreciate your advice on refactoring. I took your advice and modified my code to account for duplicates, by doing away with the dictionary. However the 8th test case still failed, hence the fundamental problem remains.

Comment: Are you still using intermediate data structures, or are you doing it in a single step as shown here? Dupes are the only significant logical difference I can surmise between my code's behavior and yours, but it's possible I've overlooked some other factor that I inadvertently fixed. The tests are unknown after all. Can you share your updated code? Without it, I can only guess at what the difference might be.

Comment: Shared the updated code. Understand where you're coming from -- your code is definitely much better, but for educational purposes I'm still interested to learn where this subtle difference that lead to failing test cases is.

Comment: Taking a quick look at your code, you've removed the dictionary but your logic is still treating duplicates as having the same identification number. Look at `ls2[ls2.index(y)-1]`, which appears to search the list for the first match found. A later duplicate will return the earlier copy's id rather than the correct one. In other words, the problem isn't specific to dictionaries in particular, it's using _any_ data structure in a way that causes dupes to map to a different id than they should.

Comment: For your approach to work, you'll probably want to build a data structure that preserves the ID alongside the element, and doesn't involve a search or lookup, which is hard to set up properly. Or just remove data structures from the picture entirely, because they just add extra steps and make the challenge more difficult than it has to be, as you now have to shepherd the data along with ids through a pipeline of operations that could simply be done right up front in one shot. This also applies to printing. On many challenges the quadratic performance of `+=` will not pass.

Comment: You're definitely right about the duplicates issue. I've managed to solve it using your advice, eliminating most unnecessary data structures, but I still preserved the use of a dictionary. It is also more similar to your solution. Major learning point on the importance of refactoring. Thanks!